# Why does Node.appendChild seemingly always return its input value?

Tags: javascript, dom

According to MDN (and other sources), it [sounds like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild#Returns) `appendChild` always returns the same value as input: either the child node or the DocumentFragment used as input to the `appendChild` method.

When I see something seemingly completely redundant in a major standard (or even elsewhere), I have to ask why - and am I missing something? Why do this?

The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/ecma-script-binding.html) itself seems slightly more ambiguous:

> **appendChild(newChild)**
>       This function returns an object that implements the **Node** interface.
>       The **newChild** parameter is an object that implements the **Node** interface.
>       This function can raise an object that implements the **DOMException** interface.

Comment: It seems like an instance of the common pattern of enabling "chained" operations: `methodCall().methodCall().methodCall()`. You'd probably have to ask the WWW standards committee for a definitive answer however.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @Pointy; I guess I'm more used to a different chaining technique and forgot about that!: `x.map(y -> f(y)).map(z -> g(z))`, which is a bit more verbose, but also more flexible; for instance, a similar effect could be achieved with `x.map(y -> f(y); return y).map(z -> g(z))` (using `return y` to allow chaining the same value as input, and assuming the values are wrapped in some mappable object; pseudo code)

Comment: Of course, this `map` style was not in wide use at the time the standard was created, I'm quite sure. At least in JavaScript.

Comment: What you describe as "the spec", isn't the spec. It's just a description of the language binding. And to an old version of the DOM spec at that. The [spec for appendChild is in the DOM standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-appendchild)

Comment: Also the DOM is not a JS specific API. It needs to be implementable in pretty much any object oriented language. In languages where functions are not first-class objects `.map(y -> f(y))` can be decidedly awkward.